# Detecting Intersection between two points IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am developing an app to show the user a route that is safe route(**Crime free route**). I am saving the lat/long of two points into the database that have been marked unsafe by the user(**Crime reporting Module**). Now I want to check that whether there is intersection between the points stored in database and the points requested by the user for the safe path so to tell the user to avoid that path? Kindly help me?

Comment: Points can't intersect. Please, consider fixing your terminology (it will make the question more clear).

Comment: So to be clear, the user uploads two lat/lngs where crime is high (let's call these points B and C). You save these on the server. Then another user uses your app to find out if the route A-D is safe. You want to check if B and C are in the route from A to D. Is that correct? (If so, that's an excellent idea! ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes **W.K.S** this is what I want to do. But I didn't find anything helpful. Please help me if you can..

Comment: **Werediver** A and D are the two points. Crime has been reported between these points by some user which has been verified. Now another user has requested for the safe path i.e between points B and C. Now I want to check whether points B and C lies between A and C?

Comment: You'd better mention other users like this: @MustajabJafry .  Two points does not define any shape (that has a non-zero area), just a line. No one operates with lines when want to say "it was there". One can put a pin on the map and say "around here ±20 meters". Then you can just check if a route is far enough from any of such "dangerous" points.